# Streaming video from S3 is choppy

Tags: html, video, amazon-s3, streaming, html5-video

I am working on a site that needs to convert videos from their original format into mp4 and ogv so I can use the HTML5 video tags. I do the conversion with ffmpeg and upload the videos to Amazon S3. I then have a Cloud Front setup to stream from my S3 bucket.

I have been able to get the videos to play in HTML5 but they are very choppy. When I have the video on my computer it plays smoothly.

What can I do to make sure my videos play smoothly?

You can see the choppy video at http://tendermercyclub.com/video.html.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The video is also choppy when downloaded to my hard drive, which leads me to believe it's a problem with the encoding. The framerate of the video is set at 20 and the bitrate is 64kb/s. This is pretty low for that size of video. I'd use 24 framerate at least, as per standard, but mainly I'd boost the bitrate to about at least 250kb/s, and see what difference it makes.